UART buffer using N-mosfet?
In this circuit, I expect that the designer needs a buffer stage for its UART (same ckt for tx and rx, but how should this work?
Thank you..

Edit: This is not a level shifter, UART is all the way (3V3)

Thx for your comment, but the BUS is +3V3, there is no level shifter happening here.

Show the rest of the circuit then. It's unclear what the voltage on the other side is. Put a bigger schematic to show where the signal to the drain comes from, and what it's connected to.

The circuit makes no sense unless the purpose why it is there and what it is supposed to do is known. Because we don't know if it does what some designer thinks it does. It might also be for partially powering down parts of the PCB so the chip does not fry up.

The drain is connected to UART header, for the rest of the circuit I don't have it, but what I am sure of, the voltage is same for the UART before and after.

It still doesn't change the main purpose and operation so the explanation(s) in the question I linked above still apply. The drain is connected to UART header then can we assume it's coming from another board? If yes then can you guarantee the signal will be noise-free? For this type of applications designers may want to stay on a safer side and implement a level translator just in case. It also brings some flexibility i.e. allow not only 3V3 but also higher level pulses.
